# Can't reach maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

Sometimes maven doesn't reach some dependency.

Surely by my fault, but I can build lots of projects, without problems with many many dependencies...

In this occasion I'm trying to get:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.cdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-cdk-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and I get:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.richfaces.cdk:maven-cdk-plugin:4.3.1.Final or one of its depe
ndencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.richfaces.cdk:maven-
cdk-plugin:jar:4.3.1.Final in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) ->
[Help 1]
```

I'm currently using maven 3.3.9 with jdk 1.8. I've also added a repository tag in my active profile referece in the settings.xml:

```
...
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles> 
  <profiles>

...
   <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from the Maven Super POM
          to activate snapshots for both! -->
      <repositories> 
 <repository>
          <id>repoId022</id>
          <name>repositoryId022</name> 
          <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/</url>
        </repository>
...
```

I've checked in my browser and I can reach the dependency path and download it without problems.

Now I'm out of ideas...can u suggest anything?
ThankS!

Comment: try and download the dependency and then add it maven or force maven to fetch from local file

Comment: @Mark , in maven central artifact id is changed from maven-cdk-plugin to maven-richfaces-resources-plugin , can you replace this and try again ?

Comment: Amit u are right. pls explain better how u point that out and I'll mark as correct answer!

Comment: @AmitK, could have verified here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.cdk/aggregator/4.3.1.Final-redhat-3

Comment: @Mark , i just went to the maven central repo and noticed the change, will update the answer with detail.

Comment: @harshavmb, link which you mentioned is not the one which mark is using.

Comment: @AmitK, got it Thanks

Comment: @harshavmb, your welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was that the maven central repository which hosts all the artifacts was missing the artifact which you mentioned in your pom.xml.

Error message was clear that maven was not able to resolve the dependencies, causes of which is normally when you specify the wrong artifact name or version.

What i did is just verified it on maven central repo.

You can search your artifact by following the base url https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ and then search with the group and artifact id. i found that artifact name is changed from `maven-cdk-plugin` to  `maven-richfaces-resources-plugin`  And below is the URL for same.
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/richfaces/cdk/maven-richfaces-resources-plugin/4.3.1.Final/

Hope its clear to you and let me know if you have other queries.

Comment: Anyways it's in a different repo: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/richfaces/cdk/maven-richfaces-resources-plugin/4.3.1.Final/